# iOS Blur effect for a view behind when showing a UIView on top (dialog)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to blur a view behind the the popped up UIView. 
Is there anyway to achieve this programatically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through many ways depending the iOS you are supporting. Here are two ways backwards compatible with before iOS8:

- [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)
- [iOS-Blur](https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur) (Similar to you implement a UIToolbar view)

In iOS8 you can use a UIVisualEffectView. The process is simple and you can checkout this tutorial of [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial) on how to do it.

Since you have asked a "programatically" way, here is a example using **iOS-Blur** library mentioned before:

```
JCRBlurView *blurView = [JCRBlurView new];
[blurView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,100.0f,100.0f)];
[self.view addSubview:blurView];
```